# Words/Expressions that means having all the qualities for creating something?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions, sentence

I am in search of expression or phrase that can be used to describe something that has all the qualities or skills to create.

Usually, I use the phrase "having all the spices for making a tournament successful."

What alternative expression/phrase can be used to replace "having all the spice" in the given sentence

Answer (score 2):

Because we usually use the term ***ingredients*** to refer to *physical substances* rather than *attributes*, I'd say this very common idiomatic usage isn't so much literal as metaphoric (alluding to things like culinary recipes)...

> [(Something has) **all the ingredients to** be a great (whatever it could be.)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22all%20the%20ingredients%20to%20be%20a%20great%22)

Note that the idiomatic element is ***to have all the ingredients*** [to do/be something]. But I specifically searched for ***...to be a great...*** there to show that this idiom is usually (but not *always*) used in "positive" contexts.

Thus it's much more likely that something/someone has [*all the ingredients to be a **success***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22all%20the%20ingredients%20to%20be%20a%20success%22) than that it has [*all the ingredients to be a **disaster***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22all%20the%20ingredients%20to%20be%20a%20disaster%22). There are **9** times more instances of the ***success*** version than the ***disaster*** version there - but more generally, [*to be a success*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22to%20be%20a%20success%22) is only **3** times more common than [*to be a disaster*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22to%20be%20a%20disaster%22) in Google Books.

---

I'd also add that to *this* native speaker's ear, *to have all the **spices*** sounds more like a simple mistranslation of the above idiom than a natural native speaker usage.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Can I some few more idiom similar to the above answer?

Comment: There's closely-related [*to have the makings of*](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/have-the-makings-of) (some end result - again, usually *favourable*), which also often occurs as [*to have **all** the makings of...*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22have+all+the+makings+of%22) But I wouldn't get too carried away with the idea of "maxing out" on idiomatic usages like this. Unless you're already *very* good at standard English grammar, vocabulary, etc., you're likely to make (minor) mistakes that will be easily noticed by the natives!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the expression ***[have what it takes](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-what-it-takes-to-do-something)*** (to do something):

​

> to have the qualities or character needed to be successful:
>   *She doesn’t have a college degree, but I think she has what it takes to do the job.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

**come together**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+together)

> 4. To happen or form successfully.

As in:

"Despite difficulties, it all **came together** for a successful tournament."

Despite all of the last-minute chaos, the party **came together** splendidly.